# Jmeter - ignore status for assertion on JDBC request

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I'm running a while controller to check if a record added to our DB before the test can continue running.
The JDBC requests fails on assertions as long as the record wasn't found.
Is there an option to use something similar to ignore status (tried it but it didn't work on JDBC request) so the request won't show as 'failed' in 'View Results Tree'

[image: assertion]

[image: While]

Comment: show the assertion you use

Comment: Why do you assert something you want to ignore?

Comment: Actually this is just my way to check if the record exists

Comment: Response Assertion that way you did it does not work ?

Comment: Response assertion is working ok with JDBC, but ignore status does not work on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mark a[Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) as successful regardless of its own status or status amended by the [Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) you can force set custom status using [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener)

1. Add JSR223 Listener as a child of the request you would like to be marked as successful
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   prev.setSuccessful(true)
   ```

   where `prev` stands for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, see [JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setSuccessful-boolean-) for more information on available functions and properties and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on other useful [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands which are available in the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

   [image]

Answer (score -1):

You can add a ResponseAssertion and checked ignore status[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ6Wg.png)